# SQL Server TOP keyword returns different results

Tags: sql-server

I have a T-SQL query to a table where I need the top row returned. In MySQL, this is working as expected, but in SQL Server, I am getting a different data returned which is quite puzzling.

I have attached three screen shots: 1 of the table design, 1 of the data returned when only viewing top 10 rows and 1 of the data returned when viewing the top 1000 rows. You will notice the very top row contains different information for the *name* column between the two queries.

The only difference in the query being the count value of the `TOP` keyword. This table has a total of 7 rows of data. The result with `Top 1000` contains the correct ordering of rows returned. What's going on here?

Why does SQL Server change the order of rows returned depending the count value of the `TOP` keyword? Can anyone explain or provide a way to keep this consistent regardless of how many rows are being returned?

[image: Table design]

[image: Top 10]

[image: Top 1000]

Comment: That is called nondeterministing ordering. You need to add tiebreaker, I.e. order by item number in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add some context in this question, what I was trying to achieve is consistency between MySQL and MSSQL in the ordering of rows returned.  I am converting a project that used MySQL over to MSSQL and this produced a problem for me.  The solution to get what I want was to use `Set Rowcount 1` to limit the number of rows returned.  This produced 1 row of data which was ordered the same way as MySQL does.

Comment: Regardless of dbms platform, in SQL all sets are "unordered" until you apply the ORDER BY clause. To assume anything else will produce bugs and/or differences (as you have seen). A good example is GROUP BY which in MySQL has the "appearance" of producing an ordered result, so some folks don't bother with ORDER BY; that is unsafe and can disappoint. So you MySQL code may have made an assumption that MSSQL has not also applied. & NB: If you require TOP(n) from MSSQL you MUST apply an order to get consistent results

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference or issue in the output. You are ordering by width and first 2 widths are same and you don't have any sub ordering so it leaves the decision up to the RDBMS (its query optimizer specifically) to present [whichever first](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2005/07/20/441053.aspx)

You should also add `itemNumber` to your `ORDER BY` clause after `Width`

```
ORDER BY Width, itemNumber
```

Answer (score 6):

`Order by` is **not guaranteed** to give same result for equal values as SQL tables represent unordered sets. And since your width is same hence you are getting different result.

To get the unique result or to make your sorting stable you need to add a column name like `itemNumber` to your `order by` clause.